# Faster way to update multiple columns for 10's of thousands of rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a process that I built, I work for a company with multiple brands (children companies).

For each of these brands the process finds all placed orders and builds a POST request to a 3rd party that provides a specific customer experience.  To do this I store all placed orders into a table. each brand gets their own table. The table looks like this essential

```
| **ID - PKey(1,1)** | **Order#** | **#OfItemsOrdered** | **#OfItemsShipped** | **#OfItemsCancelled** |
```

The process will check each warehouse system we have which are basically sql tables that indicate whether the order was shipped.

Once it checks an order it will determine if there was any changes since the last time it ran and return a SQL update string.

Once all the orders are checked it will generate a file into a folder with the update scripts like below.

There are typically 85-100k lines

```
UPDATE [].[CORP\].[tbl_Narvar_OrderLog_21]   SET ItemsShipped = 1, LastUpdateDate = GETDATE(), IsReady = 1 where NarvarID = 7132532;
UPDATE [].[CORP\].[tbl_Narvar_OrderLog_21]   SET ItemsShipped = 2, LastUpdateDate = GETDATE(), IsReady = 1 where = 7132533;
UPDATE [].[CORP\].[tbl_Narvar_OrderLog_21]   SET ItemsShipped = 1, LastUpdateDate = GETDATE(), IsReady = 1 where NarvarID = 7132534;
UPDATE [].[CORP\].[tbl_Narvar_OrderLog_21]   SET ItemsShipped = 10, LastUpdateDate = GETDATE(), IsReady = 1 where NarvarID = 7132536;
UPDATE [].[CORP\].[tbl_Narvar_OrderLog_21]   SET ItemsShipped = 1, LastUpdateDate = GETDATE(), IsReady = 1 where NarvarID = 7132537;
```

I have a separate task that will check the folder and run all the scripts..

Is there any way to speed up the process or perhaps even a different method entirely that I am unaware of to update a large number of rows where each row will have different updated values?

Comment: Wouldn't it be cleaner to have `tbl_Narvar_OrderLog_21` in your database as a table so you can update that table FROM your brand tables (either once for each brand, or unioning the brand tables into the UPDATE). Then just drop and recreate the file each night. Running tens of thousands of updates sounds atrocious.

Answer (score 2):

You can put the values into a table and use a single `update`.  As a derived table, this looks like:

```
UPDATE nol
    SET ItemsShipped = COALESCE(v.ItemsShipped, nol.ItemsShipped),
        LastUpdateDate = GETDATE(),
        IsReady = COALESCE(v.IsReady, nol.IsReady)
    FROM [].[CORP\].[tbl_Narvar_OrderLog_21]  nol JOIN
         (VALUES (7132532, 1, NULL), 
                 (7132533, 2, 1),
                 . . .
         ) v(NarvarID, ItemsShipped, IsReady)
         ON nol.NarvarID = v.NarvarID;
```

The `VALUES` clause can be replaced by an explicit table or subquery.  The `VALUES` should have alternate values for any column that could be updated.  `NULL` is assumed to mean "keep the current value", so `COALESCE()` is used in the `SET`.

At the very least, this eliminates the overhead of a separate query, commit, and round-trip to the database for every update.

Comment: Nicely explained! @Bluestreak you might want to add an index too on the NarvarID(s) as well if you haven't one.

Comment: Awesome! I knew there had to be some way better than how I was doing it.  I am going to test this tomorrow when more orders come in to see how big of a difference it makes.- @Thailo yep! I always make sure to add an index now that I realize how big of a difference it makes

Comment: `(7132532, 1), 
                 (7132533, 2, 4, 2),` would I be able to do something like that? say I wanted to update 2 fields for one order, and 3 fields for another order, would that work?

Comment: @Bluestreak22 . . . Alas, no.  But I'll edit the answer with an alternative assuming none of the new values are `NULL`.

Comment: isn't there a limit to the maximum number of values() that can be used?

Comment: @lptr . . . Not directly.  There is a limit on the maximum query size, but that is usually pretty big.

Comment: Thanks, i've encountered a max values limit for insert, but never had i thought for such a large number in an update or even a delete (albeit derived)

Comment: @lptr . . . Specifically, the length of the string (according to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/maximum-capacity-specifications-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15) is 65,536 * network packet size.  The latter is typically 4K.  I know that I have personally run queries in SQL Server that exceed 1Mbyte (alas, I don't recall how much more).

Answer (score 2):

Also simply using a transaction will vastly improve the runtime of a script with thousands of individual single-row updates.  Without a transaction SQL Server has to wait for a physical IO to the log file after every row.

EG

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
UPDATE [].[CORP\].[tbl_Narvar_OrderLog_21]   SET ItemsShipped = 1, LastUpdateDate = GETDATE(), IsReady = 1 where NarvarID = 7132532;
UPDATE [].[CORP\].[tbl_Narvar_OrderLog_21]   SET ItemsShipped = 2, LastUpdateDate = GETDATE(), IsReady = 1 where = 7132533;
UPDATE [].[CORP\].[tbl_Narvar_OrderLog_21]   SET ItemsShipped = 1, LastUpdateDate = GETDATE(), IsReady = 1 where NarvarID = 7132534;
UPDATE [].[CORP\].[tbl_Narvar_OrderLog_21]   SET ItemsShipped = 10, LastUpdateDate = GETDATE(), IsReady = 1 where NarvarID = 7132536;
UPDATE [].[CORP\].[tbl_Narvar_OrderLog_21]   SET ItemsShipped = 1, LastUpdateDate = GETDATE(), IsReady = 1 where NarvarID = 7132537;
COMMIT TRANSACTION;
```

Answer (score 1):

It is imperative to think in term of sets when dealing with tables in SQL. I suggest having a temporary table or CTE to hold value NarvarID that has to be updated.

Following SQL Queries update  table by inner joining it to #temp table

```
IF OBJECT_ID('TEMPDB..#temp','U') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #temp
Create Table #temp (ItemsShipped  int, NarvarID int)

Insert into #temp(ItemsShipped , NarvarID)
Values   (10,7132536)
        ,(1,7132532)
        -- And List goes on

        Update OL SET
        OL.ItemsShipped = T.ItemsShipped, 
        OL.LastUpdateDate = GETDATE(), 
        OL.IsReady = 1
        From [tbl_Narvar_OrderLog_21]  OL inner join #temp T
        ON OL.NarvarID = T.NarvarID
```